# It is possible to get transaction without the block number?

Tags: transactions

I would like to know if is possible to get transaction without the block number, or how to get the block number corresponds to the transaction ID.

Error 3040011: The transaction can not be found
Error Details:
Transaction b8a6c7e69ca14855ad75fc7af34dc92747a69775305c15e7d1ce243776b5f571 not found in history and no block hint was given

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you find any solution ?

Comment: Facing the same problem,I want the solution too!

Answer (score 1):

All transactions are stored in `blocks.log` file, but it doesn't have index for searching for the specific transaction by id. It costs too much to scan all blocks from genesis to head block to get transaction, so it is not supported to get transaction without block number. To get transaction by its id, you need history solutions to add index information.

- history_plugin (deprecated)
- mongo_db_plugin (deprecated)
- state_history_plugin

state_history_plugin builds historical raw data, but you need high-level tools to handle it. Refer to [hyperion](https://github.com/eosrio/hyperion-history-api), [history-tools](https://github.com/EOSIO/history-tools) or [dfuse](https://github.com/dfuse-io/dfuse-eosio).